# eclipse rcp/rap Java EE 6 security

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

I have a eclipse rcp/rap application and I want to connect to Java EE 6 EJBs... My problem is that in EJB I use some Java EE 6 standard security `@RolesAllowed ...` but I don't know how to implement this in RCP/RAP...???

I saw a way: [java ee 6 enterprise application security](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncal.html)

In web, all I have to do is to use servlet 3.0 `request.login(user, pass)`

Is it possible to have this feature in RCP/RAP... ?? I also want to check roles of users so that I know if a user have rights to see something...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about RCP, but for RAP, you should be able to do the same as in regular web apps. RAP 1.5 works with servlet 3.0.

If you're using the Eclipse workbench, you're running in the SWT_COMPATIBILITY mode (see `ApplicationConfiguration#setOperationMode()`). That means you can only access the security context from a runnable in the request thread (see `RWT#requestThreadExec()`). In plain RAP applications that use the JEE_COMPATIBILITY mode, this is not necessary.

Comment: thank you.. actually I changed my mind and I am not using jee security (I think).. because I don't find it easy to implement with rcp/rap... I will just use session beans :D but yes.. I was thinking about the same thing... thank you...